# gunicorn.service failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: server, python, webserver, django

i am trying to deploy my django project on digital ocean, and this error stoping me from doing that

MY gunicorn.socket file

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

my gunicorn.service file

```
    [Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=developer
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/developer/myprojectdir
ExecStart=/home/developer/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          bharathwajan.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

when i try to check the status of gunicorn it throws me error like this

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

[errror image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWx0A.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your Project folder is accessible to www-data group and
also project directory is correct.
Your Script looks fine!